Cómo crear un botón flotante en google site para subir al inicio de la página
Estoy preparando una web con Google Sites, pero hecho en falta un widget, botón flotantes situado en la parte inferior de la página, sea cual sea la posición respecto de la vertical, de manera que el usuario, al pulsar, pueda volver al inicio de la página dado que esta puede ser algo larga.
Sabe alguien ¿cómo se podría hacer?. Saludos

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Tienes toda la razón. A ver ahora que la he aclarado un poco, creo. En definitiva se trata del clásico botón flotante para subir al inicio de la página.

No se si Google Sites es igual a Wix o Dreamweaver (Nunca he usado ninguno) o sea  un generador gráfico de sitios web, creo que si, pero aun siendo así, un botón o ancla HTML (<a></a>) siguen siendo un botón.
No te pido que pongas un Ejemplo o código de lo que has intentado puesto que si usas estas herramientas es porque no manejas código alguno.
Si es así, lo que debes hacer es configurar un ancla <a> o un botón <button> (esto es HTML) y ponerle la dirección de tu web o lugar especifico al que ir.
Por ejemplo


<div id="arriba">
  Esto es Arriba
  <br>
  <a href="#abajo" >Ir Abajo</a>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Resto de la Web<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="abajo">
  Esto es Abajo
  <br>
  <a href="#arriba" >Ir Arriba</a>
</div>



Espero que sea esto lo que estés buscando.
